# Ist der Ausdruck "Löschen von PC" korrekt?

Tags: preposition, article

Es geht mir hier um Benutzerschnittstellen - als Beispiel verwende ich den "Falk Navi-Manager", ein Programm zur Übertragung von Karten auf ein Navigationsgerät.

Dort gibt es u. a. die Punkte "Löschen **von** PC" und "Löschen **von** SD-Karte" (um Kartendaten für ein bestimmtes Land vom jeweiligen Gerät zu löschen). Sicherlich könnte man alternativ "Löschen **vom** PC" und "Löschen **von der** SD-Karte" verwenden, und das wäre auf jeden Fall grammatikalisch korrekt. Doch erstere Form ist gerade bei Benutzerschnittstellen verbreitet. Ist sie aber auch richtig, und wenn ja, wie nennt sich diese Form des weglassens eines Artikels?

Comment: Das ist wohl der (grammatikalisch krampfhafte) Versuch, den Leser davon abzuhalten, diesen Satz als "Löschen vom PC", damit "Löschen des PCs" zu verstehen. Hat wohl damit zu tun, das man Genitiv und Dativ im Deutschen seit Neuerem so schwer auseinanderhalten kann....

Answer (score 7):

M.E. ist es grammatikalisch keinesfalls richtig. Ich würde das Phänomen eher einer oberflächlichen/maschinellen Übersetzung ("delete from" - > „löschen von“) anlasten, die ohne Rücksicht auf den Kontext vorgenommen wurde. Das dürfte ein [häufiges Problem](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maschinelle_%C3%9Cbersetzung#Grammatische_Problemgebiete_.28Diversionen.29) darstellen, wenn Quell- und Zielsprache mit dem grammatischen Geschlecht oder den Artikel unterschiedlich verfahren.

Answer (score 6):

"Löschen vom PC" impliziert, dass es nur einen PC gibt. Wenn es aber mehrere gibt und man erst nach Auswahl des Punkts "Löschen von PC" einen PC auswählt, passt es daher nicht. Dann wäre zwar immer noch "Löschen von einem PC" denkbar, das klingt dann aber schon hölzern. Hier **fasst man durch "von PC" zusammen**, dass eben von einem oder mehreren PCs gelöscht wird und nicht etwa von der SD-Karte, sprich, von einer bestimmten Art von Speichermedium (auch wenn der PC natürlich in dem Sinne kein Speichermedium ist - aus Sicht vieler Nutzer ist das aber eine gängige Vereinfachung).

Dasselbe gilt für die SD-Karte, hat aber auch schon vor Ewigkeiten mit der Diskette angefangen, hier gab es beispielsweise die Formulierung "auf Diskette kopieren". Gibt es nur eine einzige, so dass "Auf die Diskette kopieren" richtig wäre? Oder gibt es mehrere, man benötigt aber nur eine ("Auf eine Diskette kopieren")? Oder braucht man dann doch mehrere ("Auf Disketten kopieren")? Da ist es doch viel einfacher, wenn man "Auf Diskette kopieren" schreibt. Und jeder Benutzer versteht, was gemeint ist.

Ebenso umgekehrt. Du möchtest eine Software von CD installieren (ja, ich verwende das auch schon so, ohne darüber nachzudenken). Man beachte, dass "von CD" hier angibt, dass **eine Installation von einer bestimmten Art von Medium gemeint ist**, ohne dass hier ein konkretes Medium bezeichnet wird. Wollte man letzteres, stößt man daher wieder auf dasselbe Problem: Gibt es nur genau eine CD, von der man installieren kann ("die CD")? Oder ist es irgendeine ("eine CD")? Auch eine von einem anderen Hersteller? Was, wenn es mehrere sind? Auch da ist "Von CD installieren" viel generischer anwendbar (mal abgesehen davon, dass viele den Begriff "CD" für alle Arten von optischen Datenträgern als Oberbegriff verwenden, also auch beispielsweise für DVDs und BDs).

Technisch könnte die Ursache tatsächlich sein, dass es einen übergeordneten Vorgang "Löschen von" gibt und das jeweilige Objekt einfach angehängt wird, ohne dass der Text noch einmal angepasst werden kann. Dann stößt man auf das Problem, das tohuwawohu beschreibt.

Grammatisch korrekt scheint das zu diesem Zeitpunkt nicht zu sein. Aber **eine Schaltfläche oder ein Menüpunkt ist auch kein ganzer Satz**. Wenn du Stichpunkte aufschreibst, sind das auch keine ganzen, korrekten Sätze, so dass man hier bereits von der "erlaubten" Grammatik abweicht. Benutzer sind diese Art der Formulierung ohnehin schon gewöhnt, zumal "Von PC löschen" wesentlich kompakter ist als "Von einem oder mehreren PCs löschen, auf denen es (!) installiert ist". Selbst in Sätzen halte ich die Formulierung aber nicht für völlig falsch, sofern man davon ausgeht, dass der erwähnte PC bzw. die erwähnte SD-Karte eben nicht für ein konkretes Exemplar, sondern für die Gattung steht. Während ich mir diese Verwendung aber auch in anderen technischen Bereichen vorstellen kann, insbesondere bei Überschriften, Listen etc., findet sich z.B. bei Lebensmitteln aber die gegenteilige Variante: Hier gibt es beispielsweise bei Tiefkühlprodukten die Überschriften "Zubereitung in *der* Pfanne". Wie bereits erwähnt, halte ich diese Formulierung für die genannten Fälle aber für unzureichend, *sofern nicht feststeht, von welchem konkreten PC bzw. von welcher konkreten SD-Karte da etwas gelöscht wird.*

Comment: Ich möchte widersprechen. :) "Löschen vom PC" beschreibt einen generischen Akt und impliziert mitnichten, dass es nur einen gibt. "Die Mobiltelefonhalterung kann im Auto montiert werden" sagt auch nicht, dass man sie nicht nacheinander in mehreren Autos montieren kann.